# Recovering bookmarks Mac OS to Linux

Tags: xubuntu, mac, google, bookmarks

I had a Macbook air where I used google chrome with all my bookmarks. This laptop died and I bought a new laptop with Ubuntu OS 16.04 LTS. When logged in my google account, all my bookmarks were gone. This link  https://chrome.google.com/sync says that I have 195 bookmarks, but they are not displayed to me. I guess my bookmarks are on google server, but I couldn't recover them. I indeed could recover my extensions from this same link, but not the bookmarks. Can anybody, please, help me?

Answer (score 1):

sorry! I figured it out. Problem solved. I just had to sign in chrome from this device, which means that, not only do you have to be signed in your google account, but also you should sign in chrome with your google account.